# How to fix strange object is disposed exceptions when calling UWP APIs on .NET 5

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, uwp

I'm trying to call Windows 10 UWP OCR APIs from a .NET 5 Windows Forms application. The code which i'm using was perfectly working on .NET Core 3.1 but on .NET 5 it's extremely unstable.
For some reason the code throws either ObjectDisposedException or sometimes InvalidCastException. this usually happens on the call to decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync() but sometimes right on the first await.
Also, hen wrapped in a method, it usually works on the first run but on subsequent runs it fails as above.
Here's a full code sample tested on both .NET Core 3.1 and .NET 5 with the above results.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace govno
{
    static class Program
    {
        static async Task<int> Main()
        {
            Bitmap Screen = new Bitmap(500, 500);
            Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(Screen);
            g.CopyFromScreen(1, 1, 00, 0, Screen.Size);
            Bitmap S = new Bitmap(Screen, new Size(500, 500));
            var engine = Windows.Media.Ocr.OcrEngine.TryCreateFromLanguage(new Windows.Globalization.Language("en"));
            using MemoryStream memoryStream = new();
            S.Save(memoryStream, ImageFormat.Bmp);
            var decoder = await Windows.Graphics.Imaging.BitmapDecoder.CreateAsync(memoryStream.AsRandomAccessStream());
            var softwareBitmap = await decoder.GetSoftwareBitmapAsync();
            var ocrResult = await engine.RecognizeAsync(softwareBitmap);
            Console.WriteLine(ocrResult.Text);
            Console.WriteLine("OK!");
            Console.ReadLine();
            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Update: This appears to be a regression. See https://github.com/microsoft/CsWinRT/issues/640 for progress on fixing it.

Comment: I have exactly the same issue and so far have found no solution. Glad I am not alone.